# Set timeout for system call in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wget

From Rails, I make a system call to `wget`:

```
system("wget", ...)
```

I want to set a timeout for this call, so that if it takes too long (which is likely to mean too many files downloaded, or a large file downloaded), I want to stop it and return an error to the user, so that my server is not overloaded. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you specifically need to run the call in a subshell like that? If not, use timeout and backticks:

```
require 'timeout'

Timeout.timeout(3) do
  puts `tree /`  # raises an exception, which you can rescue and handle
end
```

If you do need to run it externally, though, I'd go with something like [Subexec](https://github.com/nulayer/subexec)

Answer (score 1):

In general, try wrapping the call in a SystemTimer.  https://rubygems.org/gems/SystemTimer

In your particular case, try `system("wget -T #{timeout_in_seconds}")`